# Failed audit - question is off topic

Tags: discussion, review, off-topic, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3779811), but I believe this question belongs on ServerFault since there is no specific question regarding programming, errors, etc, and it asks about http-proxying, web server integration with cloudflare, and other topics not quite related to StackOverflow.

It also requests opinions and is thus a candidate for closing as "primarily opinion based". I would say that it seems to be very well researched and thus is still a high quality post on ServerFault, but this seems to be a bad review audit in any case.

Am I wrong that this is off topic for StackOverflow?

Should the question be closed altogether since it asks for opinions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asker is developing an application stack, not administrating a server. This is made abundantly clear in the question itself.

Server Fault would be a great place for someone handling administration or deployment of such an application, but that *isn't* what's being asked about. The question is neither on-topic for Server Fault nor off-topic on Stack Overflow.